# Why is it recommended to use setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)?

Tags: java, jframe, exit

Why is it recommended to use `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` if there are ways to explicitly close the frame?

Comment: Where did you see the recommendation? What do you think the risks are by not setting a default behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Calling setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE) causes the application to exit when the application receives a close window event from the operating system. Pressing the close (X) button on your window causes the operating system to generate a close window event and send it to your Java application. The close window event is processed by the AWT event loop in your Java application which will exit the application in response to the event. If you do not call this method the AWT event loop may not exit the application in response to the close window event but leave it running in the background.

Answer (score 0):

JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE stops the application from running in background. For example, if you didn't use JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE, if your application has an active database connection, it will stay connected. To check this, you can open task manager and see the jar file still running even if its window is no longer visible.